# Inline SVGs not rendering in IE9+ when served from Tomcat 7 in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat, svg

I'm creating Eclipse Infocenter .war packages that I deploy using Tomcat 7 on a mixture of CentOS 6.5 and Windows Server 2008 machines. I have many SVG files that I take as references from human-authored XML documents and flow directly into the output HMTL as inline SVGs, since this gives me a good opportunity to size and otherwise fine-tune their presentation.

These topics all behave normally when viewed from Chrome, Firefox, and IE9+ when served from a tomcat server located on a Windows machine, but when served from a Linux machine, IE9+ fails (less than IE9 is irrelevant): any shape data is ignored, and any text data or embedded raster image data is simply read as straight text and dumped into the HTML.

My HTML test document opens like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>SVG Test</title>
</head>
```

and adds a simple embedded SVG like so:

```
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
</svg>
</body>
```

This renders fine in all major browsers when hosted on tomcat 7 on Windows 2008 Server, but fails when hosted in tomcat 7 on CentOS 6.5.

Whether this is a setting in tomcat that I'm missing or a parameter in my HTML, I'm out of ideas about where to look next. I've plundered all the "SVG/Linux/Tomcat" posts in Stackoverflow without success.

Comment: Any shape data is ignored, and any text data or embedded raster image data is simply read as straight text and dumped into the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frameset used by eclipse help was setting the content type to text/html, overriding the setting on the HTML page itself. Adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

to the head of the frameset jsp file addressed the problem.